# Windows, check when iso was mounted

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using Poweshell to mount the iso.

```
PS C:\>Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "E:\ISO-Files\test.iso"
```

Afterwards, using command line or Powershell, is it possible to get the timestamp when iso was mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Mounting an ISO utilizes the "Virtual Disk Service" so you can check for when that service started in the System Event Log:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Source "Virtual Disk Service" -Newest 5
```

That will get the timestamp of last five occurrences of the Virtual Disk Service (either starting or stopping).