# How to trigger an event when an ISO is mounted on windows?

Tags: windows, mount, iso-image, event-log

I need to run a windows service when a particular ISO is mounted. I know that an [Event Trigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/eventtrigger) can be defined to do something like this but I couldn't find an event to subscribe to.
How can I detect when an ISO is mounted? There seem to be no event logged for this.

There is a related question to this ([Windows, check when iso was mounted](https://superuser.com/q/1416484)) but the answer details how to get the timestamp for Virtual Disk Service start and stop events and not the disk mount event itself. Mounting an ISO with Virtual Disk Service already running generates no events in the Event logs and so that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the reason it does not solve the problem?  Is the event not generated?

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited the question to add more details.

Comment: You've answered your own question already. No events are triggered and therefore you cannot do what you want in the way you wish to do it.